# Vim disables syntax highlighting because of double angle brackets

Tags: bash, shell, unix, vim

I am trying to use this example in my shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='ftp.users.qwest.net'
USER='yourid'
PASSWD='yourpw'
FILE='file.txt'

ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
#### My code
#
#
```

But because of the `<<END_SCRIPT` , vim does not syntax highlights anything beyond that line. I am using red hat linux 5
Source for code snippet http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html

EDIT: May be my question was not clear. Eveyone has commented about vim not being able to highlight heredocs. But I was more concern about the code after heredoc. I should have mentioned that code is not highlighted even after heredoc is ended. **Figured out that it was a problem because there END_SCRIPT should start at the beginning of the line (no space in between)**.

Comment: Pretty sure that there's no way VIM can tell what type of code is in a heredoc.

Comment: This is more appropriate for https://vi.stackexchange.com/ . It is possible to embed one syntax highlighter in another but they have to be written to expect that I believe.

Comment: I guess down voting a question with a comment will be more helpful so that users like me and others can learn from our mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already edited my question to mention how I resolved the issue. But mentioning it here as an answer to be consistent with the format.

The heredoc was not ended because I has space between the start of the line and "END_SCRIPT".

Answer (score 3):

the region from the line following `<<END_SCRIPT` to the next instance of `END_SCRIPT` at the beginning of a line is a heredoc, which is basically a multiline string literal. vim highlights it as such, because a heredoc can honestly just contain arbitrary data and there's no good way for vim to know what to do with it out of the box.

Comment: This is useful, but I was also concerned about the code after heredoc. Edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: ah, the issue was that the heredoc never actually ended, then?

Comment: Yes. That's right since there was a space between start of the line and END_SCRIPT